# Override AcceptButton Setting On Inherited Windows Form

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010

I am working on a winforms application.  The form I am working on inherits a base form.  On the base form the `AcceptButton` property is set to `cmdOK` (basically the save and exit button).  This is required behaviour.

However, the form I am working on has a number of dropdownlist and while the focus is on them I need to change the behaviour of the enter key.

For example if the focus is on `cboTags` and <kbd>Enter</kbd> is press I need to call `cmdAddTag_Click`, if <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> is press I need to call `cmdRemoveTag_Click`.  I have added the following code:

```
private void cboTags_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter && e.Modifiers == Keys.Shift)
    {
        cmdRemoveTag_Click(new object(), new EventArgs());
    }
    else if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
    {
        cmdAddTag_Click(new object(), new EventArgs());
    }
}
```

When I tested it and found the window closed I realised the `AcceptButton` property had been set on the inherited form. I cannot find a way round it.

**EDIT**

If the focus is anywhere else on the form the behaviour should remain as it is.  It is only while focus is on certain controls I need to change the behaviour of the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key.

Comment: You can change `AcceptButton` property for inherited forms individually to (correct me) `null` or a new button of inherited form.

Comment: @Sinatr this will change in for the form no matter where the focus is.  As I said in the question I only want to change it if the focus is on certain controls. I have added an edit to make that clearer.

Comment: You already answered your question: *only want to change it if the focus is on certain controls* - handle focus events to enable/disable wanted behavior. E.g. set `AcceptButton = null` when *certain controls* get focus and reset back otherwise (i.e. manually control behavior). I don't know about easier way. Probably if you would handle `Enter` key event in base form and provide some methods/properties to enable/disable it, then it would be more easy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this.AcceptButton = null;

(or some variation which you control programatically)

**EDIT**:

By "control programatically", I mean that when you focus on a region you don't want to have the AcceptButton fire on then you run that code and then when you leave it you set AcceptButton back to what it was.

Comment: Yes, it will... When the focus is one the region where you don't want the AcceptButton to work, you set this. Then when you lose focus you set it back.

Comment: So what you are saying for each control I want to change this for I have to cancel the AcceptButton behaviour when it gets the focus, then restore the behaviour on lost focus?

Comment: Yes. Alternatively, if there are a load of these, just set AcceptButton to null and then in your key handler, fire off the button click handler for what was the AcceptButton at the time Enter is pressed and you're not in the regions you care about.

Comment: Ok so on your initial post I said this won't work and on its own it wouldn't.  However, you did give me a suggestion.  I have put a tag on the controls in question, when the form loads I loop through the control on the form looking for the tag and add two event handlers for each I find that do exactly as you have suggested.  Seems a bit clunky but works perfectly, thanks I will give you that one :)

Comment: Unfortunately, I think AcceptButton is just a nice shortcut which allows you to quickly set defaults. If you need more complex logic to determine what pressing Enter should do at any point you have to start doing things the more long-winded way.